# Reading command line output

Tags: java, command-line, inputstream

I am trying to automatically extract WinRar `.rar` files using java and the command line. One such command i am trying to execute is

`c:\Program Files\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe l E:\archives\test2.rar`

This command is supposed to list all the files contained in the archive and for some archives it works fine and produces the following output:

```
UNRAR 5.50 beta 5 x64 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2017 Alexander Roshal

Archive: test2.rar
Details: RAR 5

Attributes      Size     Date    Time   Name
----------- ---------  ---------- -----  ----
*   .......      3204  2017-07-20 19:36  a\file.java
*   .......       190  2017-07-20 19:36  a\test.java
*   .......       608  2017-07-20 19:36  a\Main.java
    ...D...         0  2017-07-20 19:40  a
----------- ---------  ---------- -----  ----
                 4002                    4
```

Other times however, it asks for a password immediately after executing the command. Whenever that happens, my java program hangs, yet nothing is printed to the process's input stream or error stream.

In command prompt the output would look like this when it asks for a password:

```
E:\archives>"c:\Program Files\WinRAR\UnRAR.exe" l test.rar

UNRAR 5.50 beta 5 x64 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2017 Alexander Roshal

Enter password (will not be echoed) for test.rar:
Checksum error in the encrypted file test.rar. Corrupt file or wrong 
password.
Archive: test.rar
Details: RAR 4, encrypted headers
  0 files
```

I am reading from the input stream like this:

```
BufferedReader stdReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
while ((line = stdReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("Read: " + line);
    stdOutput.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Yet the only output i get from that is:

```
Read: 
Read: UNRAR 5.50 beta 5 x64 freeware      Copyright (c) 1993-2017 Alexander Roshal
```

And it just hangs here. I have to force close it to exit.

Why is "Enter password (will not be echoed) for test.rar:" not printed to the input stream? How can i tell when the command requests user input (such as the password). How can i prevent my program from freezing when this happens?

**Note:** Both of these archives are password protected. One of them asks immediately before even showing the files, the other will show you the files, but asks for the password when trying to open one.

Comment: Could it be that the password prompt is sent to stderr, rather than stdout? Perhaps you need to consume the output of Process.getErrorStream() ?

Comment: I have already checked the error stream but it appears empty.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't have a Windows machine on my desk, but I checked on Linux and unrar (v4.2) definitely sends password prompts to stderr. Windows could be different, of course.

Comment: I have just tried it in a Linux VM and it does output to stderr but only if i'm using unrar v4.2. If i use the latest version 5.5, then the password prompt does not get sent to any of the streams. Very strange.

Comment: Yeah. It's always my practice, when using Runtime.exec(), to consume from both stdout and stderr. I would be concerned (but have no evidence of this) that some platforms require this. Good luck, anyway; sorry I didn't know the answer.